# Put JavaScript value inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to put JavaScript value inside HTML ?

I am trying to put JavaScript value inside HTML like below.

```
<p>
    Check your Credit Score <a href="http://someaddress.com?first_name='+ first_name +'" target="_blank">Here</a>
</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has your research shown? Hod did that research fall short?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the results, you can make use of `document.getElementById('').href` property:

HTML (added the `id` attribute to the `<a>` tag):

```
<p>
  Check your Credit Score <a id="link" href="" target="_blank">Here</a>
</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var first_name = 'Peter';
  document.getElementById('link').href = 'http://someaddress.com?first_name='+ first_name;
  
  // debug your results
  console.log(document.getElementById('link').href);
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbmz6h0g/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
<p>
 Check your Credit Score
<a href="http://someaddress.com?first_name='+ first_name +'" target="_blank"
 >Here</a >
</p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   const a = document.querySelector('a');

   const first_name = 'John';

   a.href = 'http://someaddress.com?first_name=' + first_name ;
 
 </script>
```

Comment: that's not related at all. OP asked how to insert the `first_name` variable into the `href` URL.

Comment: Oh,  I didn't understand it correctly

Comment: this may be incorrect. the `document.querySelector()` will return the first `<a>` element in the document, which might not be a good practice in the real situation. And why use `const` instead of `var`? You're changing the value.

Comment: yeah, I know `document.querySelector()` will return the first anchor element. I have used it here because I just want to show this guy how to insert the javascript variable inside the href attribute.

Comment: and i have used the `const` keyword here bcz we are not changing the value of `first_name` variable and here `const`  follows the `good practice in the real situation`.

Answer (score 3):

do this if you want to change the link
`document.querySelector('a').href = "http://someaddress.com?first_name=" + first_name;`

Comment: Thanks @brian033. I would like to put value on `first_name`.

Comment: this may be incorrect. the `document.querySelector()` will return the first `<a>` element in the document, which might not be a good practice in the real situation. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

For best practice do an if check otherwise your selector might not be found in the dom.

Also, if in `querySelector("...anything...")` not `querySelector("a")` is given the editor won't suggest the `href` prop that exists or not. Hence, setAttribute makes more sense.

```
const URL = "http://someaddress.com?first_name="

const name = 'adiat'

const anchor = document.querySelector(".what-ever")

if(anchor){
    anchor.setAttribute("href", `${URL}${name}`);
}else{
    console.warn("element not found to replace href attribute")
}

// shorthand -> anchor?.setAttribute("href", `${URL}${name}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

A robust way would be to use a token to replace, I've used `{{FirstName}}`. Use an attribute selector to select via that token then replace that token on the `href` attribute

```js
let firstNameLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='{{FirstName}}'");
let firstName = "Bob";
for(i = 0; i < firstNameLinks.length; i++){
console.log(firstNameLinks[i].href)
  firstNameLinks[i].href  = firstNameLinks[i].href.replace("{{FirstName}}", firstName); 
}
```

```html
<a href="https:someurl.com?firstName={{FirstName}}">A link</a>
<a href="https:someotherurl.com?aVariambe=false&firstName={{FirstName}}">Another link</a>
```